# How to force my F# application to run as administrator?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

For an F# application, I attempted to follow these instructions:

[How to force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator)

Alas, Visual Studio does not have the same commands and project configuration pages for F# projects as for C# projects. I have created a throwaway C# project, copied its `app.manifest` into my F# project, and modified the `<requestedExecutionLevel>` as per the issue above. Nevertheless, the `.exe` still runs without administrator privileges.

So then, how do I build an F# application so that it only runs as administrator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C# project files (`.csproj`) contain the following lines:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I just copied and pasted those lines into my `.fsproj` file just above the following line:

```
<Import Project="$(FSharpTargetsPath)" />
```

... and lo, my `.exe` now has the little shield badge on its icon and prompts me for elevated privileges every time I run it.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me so this may help others: make sure to add `app.manifest` to your project or it won't pick it up.